# unable to remove firefox session cookies

Tags: firefox, cookies, session-cookies

due to the fact that my users have configured their sessions to reopen each time they reopen their firefox browser. the 'session' cookies come back.
but my website needs fresh authentication if the session cookie is not present or 24 hours old. so I am having this problem of needing to manually remove the expired cookies each time i reopen browser after 24 hours.

to combat this, i tired to put a 'Logout' link on my page which should have helped me. but unfortunately it is not helping...

i tried below code to remove the cookies, but it seems it does not remove the cookies from the sqilte table in which firefox stores its cookies. After the following code is run, cookies reappear.. (or are they not getting removed???) how can i achieve that?

code:

```
function Delete_Cookie( name, path, domain )
{
    document.cookie=name+"="+((path) ? ";path="+path:"")+((domain)?";domain="+domain:"")+";expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:01 GMT";
}

$("#Logout").click(function() {
    Delete_Cookie('SecOne','/','.mydomain.com');
    Delete_Cookie('SecTwo','/','.mydomain.com');
    alert("Bye");
});
```

Comment: Why don't you just put a 24h expiration date on the cookie ? And if the cookie is present (= not expired), just don't rewrite it...

Comment: aren't session cookies set to expire as browser is closed? how to set an expiration date on this cookie which is being set by an other site, which i have to go for authentication. All our websites go to this 'main' website for authentication, that website on successful authentication, sets a 'session cookie' on our PCs. Now a) how can i set the expiry timer for this cookie? b) due to firefoxe's own behavior the session cookies re-appear when it is set to open tabs from last session.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although I can't say for certain what the problem is, there are a few possibilities:

The domain name could be wrong.

You could write a test delete line that doesn't use the path and domain names and see if it works then. If the cookies get deleted after that change, then it's the string you made for the delete line, or the parameters that are passed in that are wrong.

Also, perhaps it is possible another section of your code is causing the cookies to reappear. Check to see if there's any other cookie setting things that get called after this is.

Or maybe the page needs reloaded in order for the cookies to disappear

Comment: firefox is setup to reopen tabs from previous session on start. this causes the session cookies to re-appear from firefox squlite database. BUT my question is, how can i delete these cookies?

Comment: i just accepted since i was not getting any responses. firefox itself is re-adding the cookies from its database. i would love to hear if there are any method to stop that. or to remove cookie from firefox sqlite database - thru javascript.

Comment: Ok, I came up with a work around. you could also set another cookie that contains the expiration date of the other cookies. When your user uses the website, you can check to make sure it's not currently that date, and then if it is, manually delete all the cookies. I think you can "delete" them by setting them to 0 if you can't delete them by setting an expiration date.

Answer (score 0):

If the cookie is HttpOnly cookie, it is not able to read/delete from HTTPS secured webpage. If the cookie is normal one, below functionality can be used for delete cookie.

```
function deleteCookie(keyName){
        var allcookies = document.cookie, i, cookiearray = null, name = null;
        cookiearray = allcookies.split(';');
        for (i = 0; i < cookiearray.length; i++) {
            name = cookiearray[i].split('=')[0].trim();
            if (name === keyName) {
                document.cookie = name + '=000;expires=Thu, 1 Jan 1970 00:00:00 UTC; path=/';
            }
        }
    }
```

Note: Session cookies are not able to delete even browser is getting closed. This is known bug in chrome browsers. Refer below link 
[Cookie issue in chrome](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=445073)

Comment: browser is kept open for more then 24 hrs. cookie gets stale/expired in 24 hr, but is not removed by browser. therefor i have to manually remove the cookie. The auth is happening over https from another auth website, so they are secure cookies. i can not change cookies set by some other domain (master domain or another website). if i close and reopen the browser then they go away. can they just not get 'disappear' at the end of 24 hr period?????

Comment: I validated in chrome browser. It is working perfectly. Cookie expired after max-age of cookie. Which browser you are facing this issue???

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old thread but I was having the same problem as I kept trying to set a cookie with a time in the past, thinking it would expire and not show in FF cookie manager.

Setting the cookie to expire in the future but having a blank value got rid of it. Not sure why.

setcookie(mycookie,"", time()+5000,'/');

Using FireFox v40.0.3
Seems there have been a few bugs logged with Firefox and it's handling of cookie expiration.